# How do I fix my `Any` class code to output data correctly?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, std, template-meta-programming

I am trying to simulate `std::any`, my idea is to use the base class pointer to point to different types of template derived classes, to implement the function of storing different types of data, like `std::any`; thus I wrote the following code:

```cpp
class Any {
    TypeBase *_ptr;
    public:
    Any(): _ptr(nullptr) {}
    Any(const Any &other): Any() { _ptr = other._ptr->copy(); }
    Any(Any&& _other): Any() {
        _ptr = _other._ptr;
        _other._ptr = nullptr;
    }
    template<typename T> Any(T&& _data): Any() {
        /*
         * this function attempts to capture rvalue param
         */
        _ptr = new Container<T>(std::forward<T>(_data));
    }
    ~Any() { delete _ptr; }

    template<typename T> T& data_cast() const {
        if (_ptr == nullptr)
            throw std::runtime_error("Container empty");
        return static_cast<Container<T>*>(_ptr)->data;
    }
};
```

And those toolkits class is:

```cpp
struct TypeBase {
    virtual ~TypeBase() {}
    virtual TypeBase* copy() = 0;
};
template<typename T> struct Container: public TypeBase {
    T data; // those datas will store here
    Container() = delete;
    template<typename U> Container(U&& _data): data(std::forward<U>(_data)) {}
    virtual ~Container() {}
    virtual TypeBase* copy() override { return (new Container<T>(data)); }
};
```

My problem is that when I use the code like this, the resulting data is not stored in the `Container`:

```cpp
#include <stdexcept>

// paste the definition given above

int main()
{
    double y = 13.32;
    Any a = y;
    std::cout << "The data of 'a' is: " << a.data_cast<double>() << std::endl;
    /* it doesn't work here, only outputs some wrong number */

    return 0;
}
```

Here's what I understand: the compiler implicitly constructs an "Any" object for me using `y`, and then calls the copy constructor to initialize the `a`.

What I expected is that "Any" would accept both lvalue and rvalue data to reduce the copy overhead, but apparently there was something wrong with the way I was writing it that I wasn't aware of.

I tried to use the debugger to trace the process and found that the function call process did exactly what I expected. Even though I can see the pointer in `a` is valid, the output is still strange: `The data of a is: 3.10818e-317`.

I can hardly get to the root of the problem, so I want someone to guide me, or maybe I just wrote the wrong code and someone can point it out.

Comment: The `toolkits` class seems pretty incomplete. Please show a [mre].

Comment: what is "Toolkit::DataContainer<T>"?

Comment: I have used only the `toolkits` class given in the description, and in fact, only the inheritance relationship between `TypeBase` and `Container` class is used in the code given. They are literally "containers."@TedLyngmo

Comment: Please post a [mcve], that is, something that anyone can copy, paste and compile, without inventing intermediate steps like adding #includes and fixing typos.

Comment: @Kovnt `std::any` and `std::optional` are quite hard to emulate wtih only language capabilities (and did you pay attention that there are atomic properties required?)

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. What I wrote here is just a toy code that helps me understand the characteristics of cpp.@Swift-FridayPie

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're constructing a `Container<double&>` but later casting a pointer to it to `Container<double>*`.

When you pass an lvalue to a forwarding reference, the template parameter gets deduced as a reference type.  That is, in

```
template<typename T> Any(T&& _data): Any() {
    _ptr = new Container<T>(std::forward<T>(_data));
}
```

When you pass the lvalue `y`, `T` gets deduced to be `double&`.  That way the type of `_data` is `double& &&`, which collapses to `double&`.  If `T` were `double` then `_data` would be a `double&&`, which couldn't bind to an lvalue.

---

The solution is pretty simple: just apply `std::remove_reference_t`:

```
template <typename T>
Any(T&& data) : Any() {
    using DataT = std::remove_reference_t<T>;
    _ptr = new Container<DataT>(std::forward<T>(data));
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a447242b4f5cf7b7)